# what happened in this auto loop?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management

```
vector<int> nums = {1, 2, 3};
vector<vector<int>> subsets = {{}};
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    for(auto subset : subsets)
    {
        subset.push_back(nums[i]);
        subsets.push_back(subset);
    }
```

The content of `subsets`, after running, turns out to be:

```
[[] [1] [2] [2] [3] [3] [3] [3]]
```

However, I was expecting:

```
[[] [1] [2] [1 2] [3] [1 3] [2 3] [1 2 3]]
```

It seems like only the first element, which is an empty `vector<int>`, being considered.

Could you please tell me what exactly happened in terms of memory allocation?

PS: I also changed `subsets.push_back(subset)` into `subsets.push_back(vector<int>(subset))`, but it still gives the same incorrect result.

Comment: UB. Your `subsets.push_back` calls invalidated the iterators used by the range-based `for` loop.

Comment: @T.C. Could you please be more precise? Do you mean that, after `subsets.push_back(subset)`, the `auto for` loop terminates?

Comment: After UB anything at all may happen.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that will not work as expected:

`for(auto subset : subsets)` Says "Give me a *modifiable copy* of the element."
Change `auto` to `auto&` to receive a *modifiable reference*.

Range-based for-loops are intended to be used to *view a constant range of elements*. If you modify the range the iterators will be invalidated. Use a standard for loop instead.